# Second Bianchi Identity for powers $\Omega^k$ with $k \ge 1$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Let $\nabla$ be a connection on a vector bundle $E$. Suppose $\omega$ and $\Omega$ are the connection and curvature matrices of $\nabla$ relative to frame for $E$ over an open set. Then for any integer $k \ge 1$ $$ d(\Omega^k) = \Omega^k \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge \Omega^k. $$

The case for $k  =1$ is easy since we can differentiate the second structural equation to get

\begin{align*}
d\Omega &= d(d\omega) + (d\omega) \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge d\omega \\
&= d\omega \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge d\omega  \\ 
&= (\Omega - \omega \wedge \omega) \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge(\Omega - \omega \wedge \omega) \\
&= \Omega \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge \Omega.
\end{align*}

But I find it difficult to prove for larger $k$. I thought induction would do it, but for the life of me I cannot find anywhere how to manipulate matrices of differential forms. What I currently have is the following.

> Suppose that the equation holds for $k = n$. We have that
> \begin{align*}
> d\Omega^{n+1} &= d(\Omega^n \wedge \Omega) \\
> &= d\Omega^n \wedge \Omega + (-1)^n\Omega^n \wedge d\Omega \\
> &= (\Omega^n \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge \Omega^n) \wedge \Omega + (-1)^n\Omega^n \wedge d\Omega \\
> &= (\Omega^n \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge \Omega^n) \wedge \Omega + (-1)^n\Omega^n \wedge (\Omega \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge \Omega) 
> \end{align*}

Simplifying the last expression is not that clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no $(-1)^n$. Remember that $\Omega$ is a matrix of $2$-forms. Simplifying what you have if we removed that $(-1)^n$ does it:
$$\Omega^n\wedge\omega\wedge\Omega - \omega\wedge\Omega^{n+1} + \Omega^{n+1}\wedge\omega - \Omega^n\wedge\omega\wedge\Omega = \Omega^{n+1}\wedge\omega - \omega\wedge\Omega^{n+1},$$
as required.

Comment: Thank you Theodore. If you happen to know from the top of your head a resource that deals with matrices of forms and their manipulations I would gladly appreciate. @ted-shifrin

Comment: I no longer have anything resembling a complete mathematical library. Generally, there are not manipulations to do because of non-commutativity of matrix multiplication. Write it out explicitly and you can see what works and what doesn't. For Lie-algebra valued forms, there are various facts involving the Lie bracket and representation theory, and you can find this in the appendix of Chern's *Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory*, among other places. I'm sure the more modern texts dealing with principal bundles (like Tu) will have it, too.

Comment: Concerning the equation$$d(\Omega^k) = \Omega^k \wedge \omega - \omega \wedge \Omega^k$$Given two matrices of forms $A$ and $B$ am I right that $dA$ and $A\wedge B$ are defined by$$(dA)_{ij}=d(A_{ij})$$and$$(A\wedge B)_{ij}=\sum_kA_{ik}\wedge B_{kj}$$(i.e. $A\wedge B$ is simply the product of the matrices $A$ and $B$)?

Comment: @Filippo Yes, you're correct on both counts.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation!